# Using Select2 to make asp:dropdownlist searchable in a popup

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp:DropDownList that needs to have a search bar for the user to search through the dropdown.

If I remove the line 'dropdownParent: $("#ModalPanelCard")' the dropdown displays and I can search on it, but it appears to be behind the modal. Once I reference the dropdownParent, I can't even select the dropdown - almost like it isn't calling the select2. Am I referencing the incorrect parent?

Frontend Code

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ModalPanelCard">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
     <asp:DropDownList ID="selCustomerCard" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
  </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Script

```
<script>
 $('#<%= selCustomerCard.ClientID %>').select2({
        dropdownParent: $("#ModalPanelCard")
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<script>
    $('#<%= selCustomerCard.ClientID %>').select2({
        dropdownParent: $("#<%= ModalPanelCard.ClientID %>")
    });
</script>
```

Just making sure the ID is right from ASP. ASP can add extra text to your HTML id, which is why we need to make sure it's the same ID.